# Low GPU usage in machine learning computing

Tags: tensorflow, keras, caffe

My friend and I challenged a kaggle competition named "Plant Seedlings Classification". He built a keras kernel as follow :

```python
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import datetime as dt
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from os import listdir, makedirs
 from os.path import join, exists, expanduser
 from keras import models
 from keras.preprocessing import image
 from keras.applications import xception
 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
 from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
 from keras import optimizers
 from keras import layers
 from keras.applications.xception import Xception

 train_dir = './Plant_Seedlings_Classification/train/'
 valid_dir = './Plant_Seedlings_Classification/validation/'

 im_size = 299
 batch_size = 10
 train_num = 3803
 valid_num = 947

 conv_base = Xception(weights='imagenet',\
         include_top=False,
         input_shape=(im_size, im_size, 3))

 conv_base.trainable = False

 model = models.Sequential()
 model.add(conv_base)
 model.add(layers.Flatten()) # Flatten
 model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
 model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(layers.Dense(12, activation='softmax'))

 model.summary()

 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,\
                   rotation_range=30,\
                   width_shift_range=0.2,\
                   height_shift_range=0.2,\
                   zoom_range=0.2,\
                   horizontal_flip=True,\
                   fill_mode='nearest')


 valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

 print("train gen")
 train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
         train_dir,
         class_mode='categorical',
         target_size=(im_size, im_size),
         color_mode='rgb',
         batch_size=batch_size,)



 print("validation gen")


 validation_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
         valid_dir,
         class_mode='categorical',
         target_size=(im_size, im_size),
         color_mode='rgb',
         batch_size=batch_size,)


 print("train indices",train_generator.class_indices)

 print("validation indices", validation_generator.class_indices)

 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
               optimizer=optimizers.Nadam(lr=1e-4,
                                           beta_1=0.9, \
                                           beta_2=0.999, \
                                           epsilon=1e-08, \
                                           schedule_decay=0.004),
                                           metrics=['acc'])


 steps_per_epoch = int(train_num/batch_size)+50
 validation_step = int(valid_num/batch_size)+1

 print("steps_per_epoch", steps_per_epoch)
 print("validation_step", validation_step)

 model_save_path = 'xception_299_0304_nomask_epoch{epoch:02d}_vacc{val_acc:.4f}.h5'


 history = model.fit_generator(
       train_generator,
       steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
       epochs=50,
       validation_data=validation_generator,
       validation_steps=validation_step,
       callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/tensorflow/log/1'), \
                   ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_save_path, \
                                     monitor='val_acc',\
                                     save_best_only=True,\
                                     mode='max')])
```

The code will run 50 epochs.

When the kernel ran on my friend's PC (I7-7700, GTX 1060, 8G DDR4-2400), it took about `90 seconds per epoch`.

And it took about `120 seconds per epoch` when it ran on my PC (I5-7400, GTX 1070Ti, 16G DDR4-2400)

We both used tensorflow_gpu to run this kernel. My question is, why the GPU computing speed on my PC is much slower than my friend's?

We checked the GPU usage using nvidia-smi. When the kernel was running, the Volatile GPU-Util is only 30~60% on my GPU, and >95% on my friend's.

The Volatile GPU-Util can reach ~100% on my GPU when I run other ML frameworks like Caffe or Tensorflow without keras API.

Any pointer? Thanks.

Comment: I'm just guessing but there could be multiple reasons: data processing is done with the CPU and your CPU is worse. Also do you use similar harddrives? SSD vs HDD might be a factor

Comment: Thanks for replying! He also guessed that is the CPU problem, but I still wonder why my GPU usage is that low. Can I modify this kernel to improve it on my PC? We both use the same intel SSD to run the kernel.